# Difference between "@echo off" and "@echo %off"?

Tags: batch-file

At the beginning of a batch script, I saw the command:

```
@echo %off
```

To my surprise it has the same effect of:

```
@echo off
```

What is the effect of the '%' prefix?

Comment: never saw this. And indeed, the `%` is stripped by the parser, so it has no effect (at least in pure batch - but there are some batch-whatever hybrid scripts, where it *could*  make a difference). Can you give us a source? (where did you see that?)

Comment: I've never seen it before.  It doesn't work in the cmd console -- only in a .bat script.  I'd guess it's so that if someone copypastes the script into a console window rather than a .bat file, the paste won't result in prompts being hidden?

Comment: In a batch file, the single `%` sign is simle removed, hence the effect is the same as it was not there...

Comment: @rojo that at least would make sense...

Comment: @Stephan sorry, can't give source because it's from work :) but it certainly doesn't do anything out-of-the-ordinary

Comment: The answer is: A percent sign!  **`;-)`**

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I've never seen it before. It doesn't work in the cmd console -- only in a .bat script.  But I have a guess.

In a cmd console window if you `@echo off`, that results in command prompts being hidden, just like it does in a .bat script.  To reveal the prompts again, you have to `echo on`.  The difference is that in a .bat script, percent signs need to be doubled to represent a literal `%` string character, whereas in the cmd console they do not.  The result is that `@echo %off` in a cmd console results in the string `%off` being echoed to stdout.

With this in mind, I'm guessing the author intended this hack to avoid problems encountered by users who copypaste the script into a cmd console window, rather than as intended into a .bat script.  With `%` added, the command is neutered in the console, but still achieves its intended effect when run from a .bat script.  Without the `%`, the console would appear to hang after all instructions have completed.

[image: hung console]

Comment: This is genius. Just wanted to drop a comment letting you know.